# New Page with custom HTML content

Tags: page-layout, html, content, design

I want to make a new Page on a Website with my own HTML/CSS content. We got a HTML page from a designer, with content in it. I want to implement this into a normal subpage on a website. All content on the top and left side should remain the same. Only the content on this specific page should be edited.

I tried to take a content editor web part and inserted my HTML, but Sharepoint is always reformating the whole HTML and makes it useless in this way.

What would be best practice to do this?

Comment: The new page you want to host on SharePoint. Also the left navigation and top navigation of this page should use SharePoint elements? Is this your requirement? What you mean by only the content of this specific page should be edited?

Comment: Try to use SharePoint Designer

Comment: If you want to edit in the browser then content editor is way to go.  You need to decide if you want full control via HTML, or edit with the WYSIWYG.  If you want both - you need to create your own custom control  We need a bit more clarification to get you headed in any particular direction.

Comment: On the top i got the global navigation and on the left side there is the quick launch and tree view. I describe the rest of the space as content space. I really would like to use Sharepoint Designer and work directly with the code, but I am only able to edit it in browser or the page layout. I have also to use css files, bootstrap and jquery with own images. Where are the best places for them? Can i use cdns?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it..I tried with many ways to insert in team site its notp ossible. So i converted html page to master page in design manager using publishing portal .its working but i want it in teamsite with side nav and top nav...

Comment: Can you please elaborate it..I tried with many ways to insert in team site its notp ossible. So i converted html page to master page in design manager using publishing portal .its working but i want it in teamsite with side nav and top nav...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that it is possible to **split my page from the master layout** and edit the aspx file. In the content part of the aspx page, I can insert any content that should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a **HTML Form Web Part** on a page and paste your HTML into that.

You find it under `INSERT tab > Web Part > Forms` when editing the page.

Comment: This would be possible, but i do not have much control over it.